Expected number of random edges added to a bipartite graph with $n$ nodes on each side until a cycle forms
Suppose I have $2n$ nodes, with $n$ colored red and $n$ colored blue and initially no edges between the nodes. I pick a random red node and a random blue node (where the pair hasn't already been picked), and add an edge between them. I repeat this process until the graph contains a cycle.
What is the expected number of edges that have been added to the bipartite graph, when it forms a cycle?
Clearly it needs to be at least $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$, since that's how long it takes to see collisions where nodes have been picked twice and so could have more than one edge. And clearly it's at most $2n$ because at $2n-1$ if there's still no cycle then the graph is a spanning tree and the next edge has nowhere to go except forming a cycle.

@CalvinLin I mean the full pair, not the individual nodes. The same edge won't be added twice, but nodes may get multiple edges. Edited.

${n\choose2}^2$ length-4 cycles and ${n^2\choose4}$ sets of $4$ edges.  Each set of four has $6$ chances in $n^4$ of being a loop.  Pick $k$ edges, there are $k\choose4$ sets of four edges.the chance of a 4-cycle might be $\frac{k^4}{4n^4}$

If we repeat the process until $m$ edges are added, then the expected number of $2k$-cycles created is $$\frac{\binom{n^2-2k}{m-2k}}{\binom{n^2}{m}} \cdot \binom nk^2 \cdot \frac{k!^2}{2k}.$$ Here, the idea is that the first factor is the probability that a particular cycle's edges are all chosen; the second factor is the number of ways to choose the $2k$ vertices of the cycle, $k$ from each side; the third factor is the number of distinct cycles on those $2k$ vertices.
The first factor simplifies to $\frac{m(m-1)\cdots(m-2k+1)}{n^2(n^2-1)\cdots(n^2-2k+1)}$. In the very reasonable case that $1 < m < n^2$, we have $\frac{m}{n^2} > \frac{m-1}{n^2-1} > \cdots > \frac{m-2k+1}{n^2-2k+1}$, and so we may upper bound the product by $(\frac{m}{n^2})^{2k}$. The second factor is at most $(\frac{n^k}{k!})^2$. Applying both upper bounds, we conclude that the expected number of $2k$-cycles created is at most $\frac{m^{2k}}{2k \,n^{2k}}$.
Consider $m = \frac12n$. In this case, the expected number of $2k$-cycles created is at most $2^{-2k}/(2k)$, and if we sum this over all integers $k\ge 2$, we get a $\frac12 \ln \frac43 - \frac18$ or about $0.0188$. This is also an upper bound on the probability that there is any cycle. We can conclude that with probability over $0.98$, there are still no cycles after we have added $\frac12n$ edges.
It follows that the expected number of edges until the first cycle is created is between $0.49n$ and $2n$. (Actually, if we look at $m = 0.77 n$ instead, and do the same calculations, we can get a better lower bound of around $0.65n$.)

With a little bit more work, it should be provable that, with probability tending to $1$ as $n\to \infty$, there is a cycle by the time we add $1.000001n$ edges (since at this point, the expected number of cycles explodes).
The actual number of edges needed to create the first cycle will probably vary significantly in the "linear in $n$" range: there is a small-but-positive chance that we'll get a cycle after just $0.01n$ edges. So the expected number of edges required is probably asymptotic to $Cn$ for some absolute constant $C \in [0,1]$, and I don't know if there's a good formula for $C$.

The lower bound can be improved from $\Omega(n^{1/2})$ to $\Omega(n^{2/3})$ by noting that a cycle can only form when selecting an edge between two nodes that have both previously been picked. Call this a "colliding edge". A colliding edge doesn't necessarily form a cycle, but a cycle requires a colliding edge.
The chance of sampling a colliding edge at step $k$ is at most $(k/n)^2$, since at most $k$ nodes of each color have previously been picked by then. So the expected number of times a colliding edge has been picked by step $k$ grows like $\Theta(k^3/n^2)$ and can only reach $\Omega(1)$ expectation when $k^3/n^2 = \Omega(1)$, i.e. when $k = \Omega(n^{2/3})$.
